# Generate Excel report with comma separated - Shows in single column

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I have generated .**xls report using Javascript with comma(,) separated columns**. It is opening perfectly in Open Office, but not in Microsoft Excel.

**In Microsoft Excel all the columns data are displayed in single column**. Every time I should set Delimiter settings in MS Excel sheet.

Please help me to solve my problem using Javascript/Jquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comma separated will work for CSV not for XLS.

For XLS, you have to generate **\t - tab separated column values**, Else you have to manually set excel delimiters.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If you stuff the text `1,2,3` into a file and give it a `.xls` extension you do not have an Excel workbook file anymore than saving `"DOG"` as a JPEG would yield a picture of a dog.

Use the `.CSV` extension instead.